# i operator is not working with Vim in MINGW

Tags: vim, input, mingw

I installed MINGW onto my machine to open my project file. I believe I have installed everything correctly. I can open the files I need to edit and running `$make` and `$./volume` runs the program I'ù supposed to edit perfectly.

However, when I run `$vim volume.c` I can open the file and see the code, but I cannot do anything to it. The `i` operator for insert does not work. I hear beeping for most other buttons. I can scroll through it with arrow keys but I cannot seem to edit it. What am I missing?

Picture to show no "command line" at the bottom of the editor
[image: Picture to show no "command line" at the bottom of the editor]

Comment: What exactly happens when you type `i`? Does the bottom line update? Does it beep? If you type `:version` followed by <Enter>, does it show you VIM version information? Is the cursor visible (I don't see it in the screenshot)? Is it possible you've entered insert mode and didn't notice? What if you type `i` and then a bunch of text? What if you type `o` instead of `i`?

Comment: When I press i , nothing updates on the bottom line, however I can start to type on the document but not the in the way i should be able to. I have to push i to type in every single line that I want to as if the insert command resets. If i try to use keys like the arrow keys it beeps and goes back to the non-insert mode. 
-Pushing o starts a new line if the cursor is is underlining a character where-in I can type more code.

The cursor is not the "box" cursor that highlights an entire character,  it's an underline cursor.
:version gives back VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 with a lot of other stuff

.

Comment: Had to cut my comment short so heres the rest,

I used the vim editor on the uni server and it behaves wholly different than this program. I'm used to the way it aught to work with color formatting and everything and this is nothing like that. I noticed this is "MING32" and I run a 64bit operating system on Windows 8. Will that make an impact?

Comment: Also, It's fair to assume I did not install this correctly, my professor wrote a guide to install it but it was severely lacking information from the get-go. For instance, the program we had to unzip would not initially unzip because the unzip module was not installed in mingw. This wasn't instructions so he may have been lacking vital information

Comment: Upon further tinkering, it appears the file im trying to open, volume.c, nis not being recognized as a code file. It's not being converted into code in VIM like you would expect.

Comment: What do you mean by "code"? VIM edits text files. If it recognizes the language it might support syntax highlighting, but that shouldn't affect straightforward things like insertion.

Comment: The problem I feel like i'm experiencing, I had once before when I didn't save my file with the .c extension. however, the file i'm opening is a .c file. But it's not loading how you would expect, i.e. with line numbers, color coding for syntax and operators (Im not sure if thats proper but think how #include <stdio.h> is usually colored so you know it's a preprocessor.

Comment: You have two separate issues. One is you can't insert multiple lines of text. That's obviously quite serious. See the answer I just posted. The other is that syntax highlighting isn't working. See if typing `:syntax on` solves that. If not, it may be that your terminal emulator just doesn't support color. If that's a problem, I suggest posting a new question.

Comment: syntax on worked perfectly thank you so much. My professor just got back to me as well and he pointed out that "I most certainly have not added the .vimrc file to my home directory" , which I have not, so im going to do that as well.

Comment: I can't upvote but I marked it!

Comment: You talk about MinGW, but you don't mention MSYS. MinGW.org's vim implementation is **not** a MinGW application; it is an MSYS application, and thus **must** be run within an MSYS shell. Are you doing this, or are you trying to run it from cmd.exe? If the latter, it surely will not work. FWIW, I no longer use MS-Windows as my build host, so I don't use the MSYS vim, but last time I did, it worked just fine; all features supported just as I would expect, *including* coloured syntax highlighting.

Comment: I was using it from within MSYS. It turned out the problem was, I never built the .vimrc file in my host folder. So it wasn't loading the .c files how I had expected. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting your comment:

> When I press `i` , nothing updates on the bottom line, however I can
>   start to type on the document but not the in the way i should be able
>   to. I have to push `i` to type in every single line that I want to as if
>   the insert command resets. If i try to use keys like the arrow keys it
>   beeps and goes back to the non-insert mode.

Not updating the bottom line when you press `i` is normal. If you want it to show the current mode, you can type

```
:set showmode
```

or add the line

```
set showmode
```

to your `.vimrc` file (it might be called something else on Windows).

I think it's not the `i` command that's causing your problems -- it's the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. In some modes typing <kbd>Enter</kbd> sends a sequence that typically starts with the <kbd>Escape</kbd> character. If vim isn't configured to recognize that sequence, the <kbd>Escape</kbd> will kick you out of Insert mode. Arrow keys send similar sequences.

On a Unix-like system, I'd suggest looking at your `$TERM` environment variable; I don't know whether that applies under Windows -- or using the MinGW installation, which is probably different from the native Windows installation.

As a workaround, use `h`, `j`, `k`, and `l` rather than the arrow keys. (Once you get used to it, it's actually easier, since you don't have to move your hand off the home row).

And for <kbd>Enter</kbd>, use either <kbd>Ctrl-M</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl-J</kbd> (CR or LF). This is admittedly inconvenient, but it should confirm what I think is going on, and it will at least let you get some editing done.

As another test, type `i`, then <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will show you the escape sequence sent by the Enter key. (Normally that should show `^M`).

Hopefully someone else will read this and can figure out how to solve the underlying problem.

Comment: I tried to :set showmode and nothing happened.

I tried the rest of this an it's working how you say it should so I definitely think you've got me to a point where I can edit. Thank you very much for your help. It just seemed a bit off without the color coding of the functions.

Comment: I really appreciate all your help Keith. I ended up having to add the .vimrc file to get the vim program to perform how I initially expected it to. I used another post on stack overflow by someone else to get it done by using cd $home and vim .vimrc  . This got me to the point where I expected the editor to be. Thank you very much for your time. I was getting along with your "workaround" methods, albeit painfully :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to enter insert mode using the `Insert` key (usually located next to `delete`).

For a full reference, see http://www.radford.edu/~mhtay/CPSC120/VIM_Editor_Commands.htm

Comment: This does not work for me. I added al ittle more information to the above poster if it helps. I think part of the proble is I don't see a traditional "command line" on the bottom of the editor. The cursor is constantly scrolling through the code with no offical command line where I would enter the "i" operator to insert code.

Comment: I added a picture for reference so you can see no command line.

Comment: vim uses `i` to enter insert mode. I just tried using the `Insert` key, and apparently it works (I've been using vi/nvi/vim for decades and I never thought to try that). But if `i` isn't working, there's something seriously wrong. This might be a valid comment (if `Insert` works and `i` doesn't, that could tell us something), but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @KeithThompson You are right. OP's comment to this answer suggests he might have a serious problem with his vim installation.

Comment: Sorry I will update when I get back to my desktop in roughly 10 mins!

Comment: Updated the in formation a bit to keith's comment above about possibly installing incorrectly as well. Thank, you for your help! This is really frustrating and I haven't even started the coding!

Answer (score 0):

Enter `INSERT Mode` by pressing `i`. Press `ESC` key to exit Insert Mode. From there you can edit the document like so using the many shortcuts here:

http://www.worldtimzone.com/res/vi.html

If you want to learn more, google for vim tutorials.

Comment: I think I should add that i've tried pressing I to go into insert mode but its not working. i THINK it's because the cursor isn't actually at the bottom of the command window, if that makes sense. the cursor continuously scrolls through the code and I never get the command line where I can enter insert mode

Comment: I added a picture for reference so you can see no command line.